# ".s.PGSQL.5432" when trying to start Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error when trying to launch my rails server (Rails s):

```
/Users/frankydoul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When trying to understand what is going on, I was advice to call the following in the terminal

```
(base) Franks-MBP:my_app frankydoul$ ps -ef | grep postgres
  501 55027   334   0  8:21PM ??         0:02.80 /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/lib/groovy-all-2.4.17.jar:/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/jdbc-console.jar:/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/plugins/DatabaseTools/lib/dekaf-single-2.0.0.390.jar:/Users/frankydoul/Library/Preferences/RubyMine2019.2/jdbc-drivers/PostgreSQL/42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.jar com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer org.postgresql.Driver
  501 55354 27302   0  8:40PM ttys000    0:00.01 grep postgres
```

When running the following:

```
$ sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

it returns :

```
Password:
/tmp//.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I do not know where to go from here. This all happen when trying to install flutter on my machine.

Comment: Do you have a PostgreSQL server installed and running?

Comment: Yeah, the application is up and running for 2 years. This suddenly happened.

Comment: But are you sure PostgreSQL is running right now?

Comment: I just did the following to check : $ pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset. 
This means that my previous database has disappeared ?

Comment: That means that you need to say `pg_ctl -D /the/path/to/the/database/directory status`. You could also just say `psql -d database_name` to try to connect directly to your app's database.